# Grape API malformed parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-grape

I'm trying to make a post endpoint, with multiple nested parameters but the params are not as expected

I have the following parameters definitions for the endpoint:

```
params do
  requires :p2 do
    optional :p3
    requires :p4, as: :p4_new
    requires :p5, as: :p5_new do
      requires :p6, as: :p6_new
    end
  end
end
```

So I put a debugger in the first line of the endpoint and I am expecting the parameters to look like this:

```
{
  "p2": {
    "p3": 1,
    "p4_new": "Ceva nume",
    "p5_new": {
      "p6_new": 1,
    }
  }
}
```

But the actual parameters are malformed, it gives me both the newly named parameters and the old name for the parameters, in a chaotic order.
It doesn't make any sense. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Besides the fact that the first example is JSON and the second is a Ruby hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the difference between `params` and `declared(params)`. The [documentation on renaming params](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#renaming) specifies that if you want only the renamed parameters that you need to use `declared(params)`:

> You can rename parameters using `as`, which can be useful when refactoring existing APIs:

```rb
resource :users do
  params do
    requires :email_address, as: :email
    requires :password
  end
  post do
    User.create!(declared(params)) # User takes email and password
  end
end
```

> The value passed to `as` will be the key when calling `declared(params)`

I assume that you're calling `params` which is giving you both the original and the renamed parameters merged together. Switch to `declared(params)` to get just the renamed parameters.